# macOS 10.13.4 Finder displays kMDItemKind for some .java files as "Source Code", but as "Java Source" for others

Tags: macos, java, finder, file-types, macos-highsierra

On macOS 10.13.4, for some `.java` files, Finder displays `"Java Source"` for `kMDItemKind` (i.e. the "Kind" column in "List" view), but for some other `.java` files, it displays `"Source Code"`, even within the same folder.

How can I ensure that all `.java` files consistently have 
`kMDItemKind = "Java Source"`?

Here is the output of `mdls` for a file that displays `"Java Source"`:

```
kMDItemContentCreationDate             = 2017-08-08 08:51:42 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate_Ranking     = 2017-08-08 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate         = 2017-08-08 08:51:42 +0000
kMDItemContentType                     = "com.sun.java-source"
kMDItemContentTypeTree                 = (
    "com.sun.java-source",
    "public.source-code",
    "public.data",
    "public.plain-text",
    "public.item",
    "public.content",
    "public.text",
    "com.sun.java-source"
)
kMDItemDateAdded                       = 2018-02-04 06:16:53 +0000
kMDItemDateAdded_Ranking               = 2018-02-04 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName                     = "A.java"
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate             = 2017-08-08 08:51:42 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate                  = 2017-08-08 08:51:42 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode                   = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags                   = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon                 = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible                     = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden             = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery                  = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                         = 0
kMDItemFSName                          = "A.java"
kMDItemFSNodeCount                     = (null)
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID                  = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID                   = 501
kMDItemFSSize                          = 442
kMDItemFSTypeCode                      = ""
kMDItemInterestingDate_Ranking         = 2017-08-08 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemInterestingDate_RankingRepaired = 1
kMDItemKind                            = "Java Source"
kMDItemLogicalSize                     = 442
kMDItemPhysicalSize                    = 4096
```

Here is the output of `mdls` for a file in the same folder as the previous file, but that displays `"Source Code"` instead:

```
kMDItemContentCreationDate         = 2018-04-02 09:09:37 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate_Ranking = 2018-04-02 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate     = 2018-04-02 09:09:37 +0000
kMDItemContentType                 = "com.sun.java-source"
kMDItemContentTypeTree             = (
    "com.sun.java-source",
    "public.source-code",
    "public.data",
    "public.plain-text",
    "public.item",
    "public.content",
    "public.text",
    "com.sun.java-source"
)
kMDItemDateAdded                   = 2018-04-02 09:09:37 +0000
kMDItemDateAdded_Ranking           = 2018-04-02 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName                 = "B.java"
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate         = 2018-04-02 09:09:37 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate              = 2018-04-02 09:09:37 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode               = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags               = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon             = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible                 = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden         = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery              = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                     = 0
kMDItemFSName                      = "B.java"
kMDItemFSNodeCount                 = (null)
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID              = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID               = 501
kMDItemFSSize                      = 5893
kMDItemFSTypeCode                  = ""
kMDItemInterestingDate_Ranking     = 2018-04-02 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemKind                        = "Source Code"
kMDItemLogicalSize                 = 5893
kMDItemPhysicalSize                = 8192
```

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites, pick one & stick to it - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321312/finder-displays-kmditemkind-for-some-java-files-as-source-code-but-as-java

Comment: `kMDItemKind ` is different in each case.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm trying to learn how to ensure that `kMDItemKind` is the same for both files, or, if I can't do that, why `kMDItemKind` isn't detected as the same for two files with the same extension, and both of which contain Java code.